# Tesseract .NET Process image from memory object

Tags: .net, tesseract

From what I understand (I could be wrong) `Pix.LoadFromFile` is the only way to get Pix for processing. is there any other way, such as from a bitmap?

Comment: I am not professional in tesseract, but what about: Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(MyImgFilePath);
Pix img = PixConverter.ToPix(bmp);

Comment: Why don't you post this as an answer and then you can get some SO gold. as this PixConverter.ToPix is exactly what I was looking for. thanks.

Comment: you are welcome. as I mentioned before, I am not professional in tesseract, So I didn't post the answer hoping that someone else can give us more details about getting Pix(s). now I can post it as answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not professional in tesseract, but you can use the following:

```
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(MyImgFilePath); 
Pix img = PixConverter.ToPix(bmp);
```

you can take a look at source code of *PixConverter*  at : 
https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/blob/master/src/Tesseract/PixConverter.cs

Comment: If anybody is encountering `System.IO.IOException: Failed to load image` exceptions when using `Pix.LoadFromFile` or  `Pix.LoadFromMemory` - use this approach.