# Not Able To Use PixConverter.ToPix Leptonica C#

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract, leptonica

I wanted to convert a bitmap to Leptonica.Pix.. So after I did a search I found someone who had the same problem here:
 [Tesseract .NET Process image from memory object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162169/tesseract-net-process-image-from-memory-object)

So the solution to this problem  was to use PixConverter.ToPix() method.

My problem here is that I can't find this method in the latest installed Leptonica Package. I tried to remove the and reinstall the lateset version thought Nuget but the method is still not not there.

What should I do to be able to use PixConverter.ToPix()?. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that i'm using the latest Tessercat pacakge too.

Comment: Just curious, is this .net framework, or core, or standard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It lives in [`Tesseract`](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/blob/master/src/Tesseract/PixConverter.cs) namespace, more information can be found here https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract

```
namespace Tesseract
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Handles converting between different image formats supported by DotNet.
    /// </summary>
    public static class PixConverter
    {
        private static readonly BitmapToPixConverter bitmapConverter = new BitmapToPixConverter();
        private static readonly PixToBitmapConverter pixConverter = new PixToBitmapConverter();

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the specified <paramref name="pix"/> to a Bitmap.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pix">The source image to be converted.</param>
        /// <returns>The converted pix as a <see cref="Bitmap"/>.</returns>
        public static Bitmap ToBitmap(Pix pix)
        {
            return pixConverter.Convert(pix);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the specified <paramref name="img"/> to a Pix.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="img">The source image to be converted.</param>
        /// <returns>The converted bitmap image as a <see cref="Pix"/>.</returns>
        public static Pix ToPix(Bitmap img)
        {
            return bitmapConverter.Convert(img);
        }
    }
}
```

As per the sites landing [page](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract)

Add the Tesseract NuGet Package by running Install-Package Tesseract from the Package Manager Console.

Also, its worth while reading the site thoroughly.

**Disclaimer**, i have never used this library before, just looked up the information

## Update

Just to make sure i wasn't giving you bad information, I created a new project, downloaded the latest Tesseract nuget. And was able to do the following.

```
using Tesseract;

...

PixConverter.ToPix()
```

## Update2

The problem you are noticing is because you are using

https://www.nuget.org/packages/tesseract.net/

apposed to

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tesseract/

Now 'im not sure what one you actually want. However that method dosnt not exist in the former

Comment: I'm using the latest Tessercat package too and still not able to use the method.

Comment: Ok so it turned out the this method exists in 3.0.2 version.. Are you using this version> @TheGeneral

Comment: @Mick2160 yup the latest 3.0.2 for the test i did

Comment: Well the problem is that this method doesn't exist in v4+ versions.

Comment: @Mick2160 i didn't see any v4 versions, however im glad you have figured it out

Comment: @Mick2160 Updated again

Comment: That's why I need the method which I stated in the question.

Comment: @Mick2160 you cant use the other nuget?

Answer (score 2):

In Tesseract 4 there is a new way to convert this using the following syntax:

```
var pixFromByteArray = Pix.LoadFromMemory(byteArray);
var pixFromFile = Pix.LoadFromFile(fileName);
```

Answer (score 2):

i solved for myself by adding tesseract.drawing package :

[check screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhBHh.png)

just install it  and it will be solved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the version "3.0.2" for this (PixConverter.ToPix()) to work.

So your .csproj file should have this **exact** match in *version*:

```
<PackageReference Include="Tesseract" Version="3.0.2" />
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am using 3.3.0 and the issue still persist.

Comment: @PratapSinghMehra did you try with version 3.0.2 ?

Comment: No. So I used Pix.LoadTiffFromMemory(fileBytes)) method